# C++ comparing two ints, error or wierd end

Tags: c++, compare, codeblocks

i use C++ in CODE:BLOCKS and ive made a little game with login, so when i wanna compare a variable(int) that came from scanf and a variable that i made, that wont work. So in the program i log in with a name and a pw, that works, than i get an exercise like: 65+34 and if i type ANY numbers, it will crash, if i enter a letter, it will say "A valasz rossz" that means my answer is incorrect, sorry for the hungarian program... translates:

- A valasz helyes - answer is right
- A valasz rossz - answer is wrong
- Jatek! Valaszolj a helyesen- Game!Answer correctly
- Bejelentkezes! - Login
- Felhasznalonev - Nickname
- Jelszo - pawssword
- On meg nem regisztralt! 1 Regisztracio 2 Kilepes - U havent
  registered yet! 1 register  2 Exit
  So i think the problem is at the criterion if(ans==eo)
  CODE:http://pastebin.com/E0AbRx8y   HELP AT 104. LINE
  Thanks for helping, it would be a lot for me! <3

Comment: Please get the important part of your code into the question, it will get you a faster answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
scanf("%d",ans);
```

`'scanf()'` stores values, so it needs a place to store them.
This is done by providing the addresses (in pointers) of
where to store the values.

So write:

```
scanf("%d",&ans);
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In line 103, you need to pass scanf the ADDRESS of the variable where you want to store the value, so instead of:

```
scanf("%d",ans);
```

You should do:

```
scanf("%d", &ans);
```

You probably need to review all your calls to scanf and:

1. Ensure that you pass a pointer to the output variable
2. Check the return value in order to verify that you've read successfully the user's input (e.g. detect if you expect a number and the user enters a word)
3. Use C strings (arrays of char, which work with the printf and scanf functions) instead of C++ strings (std::string, which work with the >> and << operators)

Hope that it helps.